# Using variable in new page Rail 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to create a new page in Rails 5, pass a variable that is being used in my program, and use it from that new page. I'm sorry if this is obvious, I'm only learning.

My code looks like this:

I have a folder in my view called **Users**. This folder consists of *show/edit/index/view* files. From the index view, I have written,

```
<%= link_to "Profile", profile_path(@users) %>
```

In my routes I have:

```
get 'profile' => 'users#profile'
```

Inside the **Users** folder, I have a view file named **profile.html.erb**.

From within the profile view, I'm trying to use *@users*, but *@users* is nil.

Comment: The variable is already created, and it's being used with no problem from the other views, but now I wanted to use that variable from my new page and it's coming up nil.

Comment: Do you want access to some specific user within the `profile` method or all the users in the `@users` variable? I guess is `@users = User.all`.

Comment: if you want some help that is going to be of any kind of use to you, you will need to provide your controller file and view files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `profile` method and your routes aren't defined to expect nothing then if you do:

```
<%= link_to "Profile", profile_path(@users) %>
```

Then you'll see just an `a` tag with an `ActiveRecord_Relation` in its url, if you do:

```
<%= link_to "Profile", profile_path(user) %>
```

Then you'll see just an `a` tag with the `id` of that user (`users.1`), which is the user taken from the iteration of each element within an `@users` variable.

If you want to pass a variable from one controller to another one (or also the same but different actions) through a `link_to` helper then you need to pass it referencing the `param` it'll take, you can do:

```
<%= link_to "Profile", profile_path(user: user) %>
```

And this will send a param called `user` which you'll be able to access through `params[:user]` in the controller:

```
def profile 
  @user = User.find(params[:user])
end
```

The variable is `@user`, just one user, it'll be available in the view which responds to `users#profile`.

If you want to send a `@users` variable to the controller and there to do whatever you want, then the same way, and then in your controller you can "reassign" it:

```
# view
<%= link_to "Profile", profile_path(users: @users) %>

# controllers
def profile
  @received_users = params[:users]
  ...

# the view which responds to the profile method
<%= @received_users.inspect %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way you're passing @users into your index view through your index method in your controller, you would pass it into the show view through the show method. But what I think you're trying to do is link to that profile, so you would do

```
<%= link_to "Profile", profile_path(user.id) %>
```

assuming you didn't manually change your routes to not use ID's in urls. This is also assuming that you've looped through @users something like this

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= link_to "Profile", profile_path(user.id) %>
<% end %>
```

Your controller would look something like this:

```
def show
   @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
end
```

this would give you access to that user in the view.

Comment: Just to mention `profile_path(user)` will work too and `find_by_id` can be replaced with `find`.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but from my new page, **user** is nil when I try to use it.

Comment: Mine or Ted's?, how are you accessing that __user__?

Comment: In regards to Ted's suggestion. The **user** has been used throughout the index view without problem, but then I wanted to link to another page and use it there, I think there's something really basic that I'm missing here.

Comment: Could you add the controllers you're working with to the question?

Comment: I have `def profile
    @users = User.find(params[:id])
  end`

Comment: I've made an answer.

Comment: note that if you use `find` instead of `find_by_id` your application will raise an error if the user cannot be found by that id instead of returning nil